# Change the pdf direction to the right (RTL) | rialto-php - puppeteer

Tags: php, laravel, puppeteer

**The Question**

Is it possible to change the orientation of the pdf file according to the language when the Arabic language is RTL and in the case, if it is in English it is LTR?

I control it through the HTML page and it is displayed on the HTML page in this way, but in the PDF file it does not change like the HTML

**The Package used**

https://github.com/rialto-php/puphpeteer

**Screenshots**

**Screen From PDF**

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17188078/134364972-a38058e1-0c11-47d0-a75f-f7219cec8441.png

**Screen From HTML Page**

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/17188078/134365099-ef26e05e-6ddf-4c3c-abbe-df2fd695bf01.png

**My Code**

```php
$page->pdf([
    'path' => public_path(sprintf('pdf/reports/%s.pdf')),
    'printBackground'=> true,
    'format'=> "A4",
    'direction' => 'rtl', // Not Working
    'margin' => [
        'top'=> "0px",
        'bottom'=> "0px",
        'left'=> "0px",
        'right'=> "0px",
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Presumably if such a feature exists, it will be in the documentation for the package. Does the text correctly switch to RTL and just the layout is the problem? Or does it not support RTL at all?

Comment: Not support RTL at all in PDF, Please check the images uploaded

Comment: The question should stand alone without images, and to someone unfamiliar with Arabic script it's not simple to tell the difference between LTR and RTL.